# A question related to continuous functions in general topology.

Tags: general-topology

> ***Q.*** Let $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and the topology on $X$: $\mathcal T=\{\varnothing,X,\{0\},\{0,1\}\}$. A continuous function $f:X\to X$ is such that $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=1.$ Find $f(0).$

**My work:** Since $f$ is continuous, it must be continuous at each point in $X.$ That is, $f$ is continuous at $0\in X$ as well.

If possible, let $f(0)=2.$ As $2\in X$ and $X$ is an $\mathcal T$-open subset in $X,$ codomain of $f.$ So in this case, $X$ is a nbd of $f(0).$

Now, $f^{-1}(X)=X$ which is an open subset of $X$ (domain). We also have $0\in X$ i.e., $X$ is a nbd of $0.$ Thus, we find that: if we let $f(0)=2,$ then the inverse image of nbd of $f(0)$ becomes a nbd of $0$ and hence $f$ becomes continuous at the point $0\in X,$ as desired, and so indeed $f(0)=2$ is the right choice. (Also, $f$ being a function there exists no other value of $f(0).$)

I don't know the answer to this question. So, just to be sure, I want to know whether I am correct or not. Also, if I am correct, is there any other approach to get the same result without making the assumption $f(0)=2$ at the beginning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is actually that $f(0) = 0$.

The general definition of continuity is that $f : A \to B$ is continuous iff for all open sets $U \subseteq B$, $f^{-1}(U) \subseteq A$ is open.

In this case, note that $\{0\}$ is open, and thus $U := f^{-1}(\{0\})$ is open. Note that $1 \in U$. Also note that for all open $V \subseteq X$, if $1 \in V$ then $0 \in V$. This can be proved by examining each open set one by one.

Therefore, $0 \in U$. Then $0 \in f^{-1}(\{0\})$. Then $f(0) = 0$.

Edit: I think I'm starting to see where the confusion lies. Let me solve an analogous problem.

Consider $a \neq b \neq c \neq a$. Define $Y = \{a, b, c\}$. Define $\mathcal{T}_Y = \{\emptyset, \{a\}, \{a, b\}, \{a, b, c\}\}$.

Suppose we're given a continuous function $Y \to X$ such that $f(c) = 1$ and $f(b) = 0$. What is $f(a)$?

The answer is that $f(a) = 0$. To see this, consider the fact that $\{0\}$ is an open set in $X$. Therefore, since $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ must be an open set in $Y$. Let $U = f^{-1}(\{0\})$.

We know that $f(b) = 0$. Therefore, $f(b) \in \{0\}$. Therefore, $b \in f^{-1}(\{0\}) = U$.

Let's look at all the possible values of $U$. Since $b \in U$, that means that either $U = \{a, b\}$ or $U = \{a, b, c\}$. Either way, we see that it must be the case that $a \in U$.

Since $a \in U = f^{-1}(\{0\})$, we see that $f(a) \in \{0\}$. Therefore, $f(a) = 0$.

Now that we've established that $f(a) = 0$, just take $a = 0$, $b = 1$, and $c = 2$. Then $Y = X$ and $\tau_Y = \tau$. So we see that $f(0) = 0$.

Comment: Sorry to ask too many questions (may be lame) sir but I have few doubts. Please clarify: 1. How can we be so certain that $1\in U$? 2. As you have mentioned, both $0$ and $1$ are in $U.$ So why not $f(0)=1$? 3. Will you please point out, where exactly I went wrong?

Comment: @Usual_Learner (1) $1 \in U := f^{-1}(\{0\})$ because $f(1) = 0 \in \{0\}$. (2) The fact that $1 \in U$ does not mean $f(0) = 1$ is possible.  (3) Your proof does not make enough sense to me that I can determine where you went wrong.

Comment: @Usual_Learner Take a look at my revised answer and let me know if it helps you to understand what's going on.

Comment: Sir, it's crystal clear now. Thank you so much for providing so much of your time to make me understand. Sir, one more thing that I'd like to ask: In my work, I tried to use the fact that if a function between two topological spaces is continuous then it must be continuous at each point in its domain and that if I assume a value for $f(0)$ and can show that for that particular value that the above mentioned fact holds then I'm done. But as you have derived $f(0)=0.$ Then certainly $f(0)\ne 2.$ But I'm not able to make out where I went wrong. Please shed some light on it.

Comment: @Mark_Saving And sorry for replying too late. Actually it was past 2 am, here in my country, last night when I posted this question and back then I was not able to make out your answer properly so I slept and took some time to think about it after waking up this morning. Thanking you again!

Comment: @Usual_Learner The problem with your proof was that you started out by assuming that $f(0) = 2$. You then did not actually prove that the given $f$ was continuous. That would require you to show that for every $x \in X$, for every neighbourhood $U$ of $f(x)$, $f^{-1}(U)$ is a neighbourhood of $x$. You only did this for one specific $x$ and one specific neighbourhood of that $x$.

Comment: Oh okay, got it sir. You have cleared my misconception regarding the very definition of continuity here. It was really helpful. Thanking you again.